# uneven pull ups

Tags: exercise, muscle, pull-ups, back, bodyweight

[image]
when i do a pull up my right shoulder seems to be higher and i don’t know why. anyone know how to fix this? i am right handed if this helps

[image]

Comment: Have you been evaluated for scoliosis?

Comment: no i have not why?

Comment: it could be just a muscle imbalance, your right side is possibly stronger than the left since you're right handed.

Comment: how do i correct this? should i keep doing pull ups and wait for it to even out?

Comment: @alexmcross Assuming your photo shows you pulling with equal strength, your right shoulder is slightly higher than the left.  There's a visible slope from your right shoulder down to your left.  This **may** indicate a problem with your spine.  Additionally, your photo may also show poor form.  It's difficult to guess without a proper evaluation.  A photo is not sufficient to "diagnose" any potential problems.

Comment: it doesn’t feel like i’m pulling more with one side i only noticed it when i recorded myself, maybe my right trap or shoulder or back is tighter than the left? i hope it’s not my spine lol